How do i put a HTML file inside a python tkinter window?
I've tried looking for an answer for almost 2 days, but I still couldn't find one. Could someone please help me?

Do you mean render an html file as some graphical interface, or as a link to download? does this answer your question?

I meant as in like how a local HTML file can be viewed inside a browser, would it be possible to view a local html file inside a tkinter window?

Yes, did you check out the link I provided?

yes I just did, but when i tried to pip install cef python it shows "
A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 24.0
To update, run: python .exe -m pip install --upgrade pip"
and when i did what it said, it shows "
File "", line 1
-m pip install
^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"
what should i do?

python -m pip install --upgrade pip doesn't upgrade for you? This might be outside the scope of your question

ok maybe il search somewhere else for that error thanks

You can use the tkinterweb for this!
Read the documentation for more details.
 pip install tkinterweb

Some example:
    import tkinterweb
    import tkinter
    
    
    def load_website():
        frame.load_website(entry.get())
    
    
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title('MiniBrowser')
    
    tkinter.Label(master=root, text='> Browse some website :D <').pack()
    
    entry = tkinter.Entry(master=root)
    entry.pack()
    
    button = tkinter.Button(master=root, text='Go!', command=load_website)
    button.pack()
    
    frame = tkinterweb.HtmlFrame(master=root)
    frame.pack()
    
    root.mainloop()
    


is there a way, instead of websites to make it view local html files?

You can use the method load_file or the load_html too. There are some good methods in tkinterweb, unfortunatly do not show pages as a full browser but works for something xD

ok i will try tysm!
